# Wiremock path param array of 100 values

Tags: wiremock

API Specs:

GET /customer/{{customerId}}

My Target response:

1. Input: "/customer/[any customer id in a list of 100 valid values], Output: 200 with the customer details json object as response
2. Input: "/customer/[any value not in the 100 valid values]: Output: 400 not found error

You may be asking why don't we just use a matching pattern? Yes I get that point but we are dealing here with pre-existing data that have no common pattern, that why why we result to this solution.

Is there a way to put the 100 values in an array or something? rather than create 100 specific urls for each value?

I tried looking at the wiremock specs but can't find any related to this. Is this possible to do?

https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

Comment: Is there a reason you have to match all 100 as the 200 response? Could you make that list smaller and still achieve the same results (a set of users with 200 responses)?